# Adding Subscribers to a Publication list without sending an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import, publicationlist

I understand that the easiest way to add a subscriber to a publication list is to email them, however, our business wants to handle a newsletter campaign using marketing cloud, and they want to avoid sending multiple confirmation emails to add the subscribers (5 newsletters would be used.)

So, my approach has been to build an automation with 5 steps,
[image]  my idea is to run that automation daily and add the contacts/leads created on that day to each publication list, the first step is SQL activities that will get Leads and Contacts from Salesforce, checking a control checkbox that determines if the lead/contact must be added to that publication list.

This is how the queries look:  for leads [image] and for contacts [image].

And the data extensions: [image], they all have the same fields.

Then on step  3 I have the file transfer activities: [image][image][image]. The only thing that changes between them is the name of the file.

And then we have the import file activities: [image], [image], [image], [image], [image]

Everything looks good for now, but when I run the automation, all the file import activities get errors, and the error message doesn't give much detail: [image]

I have tried changing the order of the columns in the mapping, verified that DE Ids and file names are correct but haven't been able to make it work.

If you have any insight, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a notification email for the import activity? What does it say?